Text to Columns issue in Macro
I'm trying to record a macro that includes a step that separates first names and last names into two columns using the Text to Columns function. When I run the macro, I get a Run-time error '1004': No data was selected to parse. Can someone look and see if you can help me on this?
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

I've tried to look up answers to this and someone had mentioned to use relative references which didn't change my result.

When starting with .Selection it means something needs to be selected.  Or you can specify the range directly: Range("A1:A1000")

Without data to separate, it's throwing RTE1004:  No data was selected to parse, because there is no error handling when you don't have a selection with data included.  Example, you type cat dog into A1, press enter, your selection is now A2; run your macro and you get RTE1004, due to the cell being empty and having no contents.

Issue can be resolved with error handling, in case you have a blank cell:
    If InStr(Selection.Value," ") > 0 Then Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

I chose Instr() to check for the space, so it can separate, as opposed to Len()>0 since it was more specific to the request.

Edit1:
Screenshot of what I tested (note that A4 is just " " which does populate N1); as is, this macro will split a 3-part name or into 3 columns or 2 part name into 2 columns).


If InStr(Selection.Value, " ") > 0 Then Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

I copied this in and am now getting Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

@RachaelPaar What is the data you're using when you get the type mismatch?  After testing with several options, I have yet to receive an error using the InStr(," ") check.
